# How to manage Roles in asp.net using FORMS

Tags: asp.net, forms, roles

So I'm making a login system for my asp.net site. There are 3 different types of users. I've discovered that FORMS can manage roles so I decided to try this.

I have everything working with authentication in FORMS currently - but without roles. I found this piece of code that should limit access to a specific page. But everyone can still access that page. which is odd because I haven't added anyone to the role "member". to start off with I only added 1 role to see if people were blocked from the page.

```
   <configuration>

    <connectionStrings>
  //EDITED
 </connectionStrings>
 <system.web>

   <roleManager enabled="true" />

   <customErrors mode ="Off">

   </customErrors>

   <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms name=".ASPXAUTH"
            loginUrl="login.aspx"
            protection="All"
            timeout="30"
            path="/">
     </forms>
   </authentication>

   <authorization>

     <deny users="?" />
     <allow users="*" />

   </authorization>


    </system.web>

  <location path="RandomPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Member" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <system.webServer>


    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Code for adding the roles to FormsAuthenticationTicket. P.Userole contains the string"Member"

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                1, //Ticket version
                p.firstName, //username
                DateTime.Now, 
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), 
                false, //true for persistant user cookie
                p.userRole+"",
                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
            string hashCookies = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashCookies);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sure, you did not add roles to the `FormsAuthenticationTicket` after successfull login. It should be like...

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, "UserId", 
DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, "ListOfRolesCommandSeperate", FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
    string hashCookies = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashCookies);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

You need to pass the roles of the logged in user to the `FormsAuthenticationTicket` to get it work. As you just added permission rights only in the web.config file.

Comment: But if I didn't add any roles the person shouldn't be able to access the RandomPage. Which he can, but yeah adding roles to the ticket wouldn't be a bad idea :) so:

What does the number 1 mean just before UserID?

and CommandSeperate means it would have to be like this: "Admin,User,Member" right? - English is not my first Language

thank you for this answer :)

Comment: Using the above I've managed to add roles, and retrieve them using 


FormsIdentity id =
                (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;

                string userData = ticket.UserData;
                string[] roles = userData.Split(',');
                HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(id, roles);



But it still doesn't block users without the role from RandomPage.

Comment: <location path="RandomPage.aspx">, if you are restricting user to specific page, then provide page extension as well.

Comment: If that particular page in speecific folder then you need to provide with full path like... <location path="FolderName/RandomPage.aspx">

Comment: Thanks a lot now I actually get an error =D Really nice help, so it says there's something wrong with the role manager. I placed that inside the Location tag, actually thinking that was wrong. Where should it be placed or can it just be removed?

Comment: You can check at your end, how it work fine, do what you see right.

Comment: I deleted the manager, Now i get kicked back to the login screen if I'm not allowed to view the page. problem is that even though I have the role I get kicked back to the login screen. I'm really getting closer to finish this I think. Now I just need to figure out why it blocks everyone

Comment: Now are you adding the roles in a way how i specify in my answer ?

Comment: Yes and I can retrieve the role using the code I pasted in my second comment. I'm currently just looking through it all. Do you want me to post the code? that would probably be a lot easier as I currently have no clue what the problem could be.

Comment: did you understand my code? Yah it would be better if you post complete code.

Comment: I'm not that much into Cookies, other than they store information. So you send an encrpted cookie back to the user. My cookie didn't have the userroles - I guess that's what happening, else please enlighten me :) I edited my first post with what my code looks like now

Comment: Your code seems to be OK to me. There might be other problem. I can't say anything. By the way tell me your Error message which you got ?

Comment: I'm not getting the Error anymore, it just throws me back to the mainpage. I was thinking, what does the rolemanager exactly do? Because I can remove it and still run the code without any errors, so it doesn't do anything it seems.

Comment: what role have to your logined user? is that user have that role ?

Comment: Yes he has the member role Which the location should accept. I really don't get this, I've just gone through it all again. I tried with other roles and still the same. It's not the web config file that is set up wrong or something? I don't have anything that works to look after. I've taken my code from various sites so my guess would be that I messed up somewhere hehe..

Comment: HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Member") returns true.

Comment: Ahan, just see your question again, the problem is here,  <deny users="*" /> and it should be  <deny users="?" /> ' * ' deny to all and ? mean deny to unautheticated user.

Comment: People have already logged into the site when they try and access these pages, meaning they're authenticated. So <deny users="?"> wouldn't do anything. Everyone should be denied from entering the RandomPage except people with the roles. Denying should be: people who have logged in but lack the roles.

Comment: Please test it with what I have advise you in the above comment. Try to test all scenario. It will work I hope.

Comment: I tried it, but it just allows everyone then. What is funny is that I tried <Deny roles="newRole"/> then giving the user that role instead. He wasn't blocked. I really don't get this. it's probably something very simple I am missing. I wish I had a full example of roles. I was wondering. The Authorization tag in the locations tags can't it conflict with <authorization>

     <deny users="?" />
     <allow users="*" />

   </authorization> just after the authentication tags? I mean the last is for the whole page the other just for that location?

Comment: this is what i have used for my application ...  <location path="Admin/ChangePwd.aspx">
  <system.web>
   <authorization>
    <allow roles="BranchAdmin"/>
    <deny users="?"/>
   </authorization>
  </system.web>
 </location>

Comment: Can I see your whole Config file? just post it in a new answer - then it's easier to read, You've been very helpful :)

Comment: Did you see web.config, now Can I delete that answer ?